# Cordova : Facebook plugin : showDialog apprequests

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, apprequests, facebook-app-requests

I installed last month the [Facebook plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) for Cordova. Last week I implemented the [showDialog](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin#show-a-dialog) to let people invite their friends to the app using "apprequests" method. It worked when I tried with two friends, they got the invites.

Today, trying again, everything works fine - except that the people I invite never get any notification.

Here is the code of the call (using [NGCordova's wrapper](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/)) :

```
$cordovaFacebook.showDialog({ method: "apprequests", message: "Come on man, check out my application." })
    .then(function(success) {
        console.log("success", success);
        // success
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        // error
    });
```

The console shows success :

```
success Object {to: Array[3], request: "id_of_request"}
    request: "id_of_request"
    to: Array[3]
        0: "user_id_1"
        1: "user_id_2"
        2: "user_id_3"
        length: 3
```

The user ids were good also. But no notifications for them on their Facebook account.

What I tried so far :

- Reinstalling Facebook plugin
- Create another Facebook app and use its credentials instead
- Installing the latest version of NGCordova (unlikely to help, is simply a wrapper...)
- Using other methods, like "feed", and post to my wall - it works.

Taking NGCordova out of the picture, using basic function behave the same :

```
facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog({ method: "apprequests", message: "Come on man, check out my application." }, function(success) {
        console.log(success);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

This triggers success as well and still no notifications.

Thanks ahead for any help, I think I'm out of ideas...

Answer (score 3):

Just publish your app in Facebook Developers , under the Status & Review , make it live > "Yes"

Answer (score 0):

Hey have you the check the notification in the facebook mobile app?